# Navigation history consistency in JSF application

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, navigation, servlet-filters

I am developing a `JSF` application and I want to preserve the history consistency regarding to navigation back and forward. In particular I can give this example:

There is page `overview.xhtml` and its backing Bean `OverviewBean`. It presents a list of items in a `datatable`. I have a link on each row of `datatable` which leads to the `item_details.xhtml` view of each presented item:

```
<h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Edit</f:facet>
        <h:link value="Edit" outcome="/item_details">
            <f:param name="itemId" value="#{item.id}" />
        </h:link>
</h:column>
```

The user can edit the item data and save the changes by clicking the submit button of the `item_details.xhtml` which leads back to the `overview.xhtml` page. This works with a `h:commandButton` and the appropriate action method:

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{itemDetailsBean.update()}" /> 

   public String update() {
        itemEjb.updateItem(updatedItem);
        return "overview.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

The user is again as expected on the `overview.xhtml` page. In this case however the browser back button leads back to `item_details.xhtml` page and if pressed once more to the `overview.xhtml` again. In other words if one follows a navigation route

```
overview -> item_details_3 -> overview -> item_details_5 -> overview -> item_details_2 -> overview
```

has the (undesired) possibility to go back this route in the reversed direction. 
My intention is the `overview.xhtml` page to act as the `root page` and the back button on that page to lead the user out of the application or to prompt for logout. In other words I would like the navigation to work as a stack:

```
forward: push(page)
back:    pop(page)
```

How can I achieve that in `JSF`? 
I know there are similar posts but nothing has worked for me.
I have tried also a `NoCacheFilter` as:

```
@WebFilter("/faces/*")
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (!request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
           response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
           response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
           response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

}
```

Although the method `doFilter` is called, it has no effect on the navigation.

Comment: Is Ajax navigation an option?

Comment: Yes, it could be an option. I would take into consideration a solution based on Ajax navigation.